# Process a large file in background with Play Framework

Tags: java, file, playframework, akka

What is the best way to process a large file with play framework? I need to execute some operations when a file was uploaded. Process can be slow then I need to return http 200 to client and send an email when the process ends

I was googling and I found these approaches:

1. Create an Actor
2. Create a new thread
3. Create a promise (CompletionStage without a .get())

Those approaches works, but I'd like to know what is the best or clean one

Answer (score 0):

I think creating an Actor can be an eligant solution. Since you processing a huge fil, using stream processing engines either fs2/akka should help

Answer (score 0):

I am using the actor based system for similar problem as yours and it works very well.
For reference and trying out you can refer to this
https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/create-actors.html